# Multiple Layouts in Laravel Blade, Vue-Router

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-router

I am trying to separate user & admin functionality but can't find a satisfactory solution.

After login, the user is authenticated and then he is redirected to either user or admin blade view depending upon the role.

"Now, in the `user.blade file`, I just want to load user-related routes & components and vice versa. This way, I won't need any ACL in Vue-router and extra fuss, I guess".

But how do I make this work? I have searched everywhere but can't find a proper solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 3 different JS files, like `vendor.js` for e.g. Vue and other libraries, `app.js` for the user area and `admin.js` for the admin area.

Then in `user.blade.php` you include `vendor.js` and `app.js` and in `admin.blade.php` you include `vendor.js` and `admin.js`.

`app.js` will include all routes for the normal user, while `admin.js` will include all routes/components etc for the admin area.